# roots of recursive polynomials

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I have recursive polynomials

$$Q_{n}(t)=tQ_{n-1}(t)+\frac{1-t^{2}}{n+1}Q'_{n-1}(t)$$

and

$$Q_{0}(t)=1$$

Is there a theory for finding a factorisation of recursive polynomials?

It is possible to show that 
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}sinc(\pi(x+s))^{p+1}=Q_{p-1}[cos(\pi x)]$$
where $$sinc(x)=sin(x)/x$$

Maybe you have some ideas for my case?

Comment: What is "$sinc$"?

Comment: And what does $s$ vary over in the summation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have realised that your recurrent relation is exactly the one which appears in Eq. (2.4) in [[*Izvestiya: Mathematics* **66**:3 (2002) 489--542]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/IM2002v066n03ABEH000387) (see
also [here](http://wain.mi.ras.ru/PS/zete_main.pdf)). The properties of the corresponding polynomials are expressed in Lemma 2.2 and around (they seem to be exactly the ones you are trying to establish).

Comment: Wadim, it looks to me that the denominator $n+1$ here should be $n-1$ to match the recurrence relation (2.4) from your paper. I don't know if that matters much though.

Comment: Vladimir, are you the author? :-) Yes, you are right but shifting the index of the sequence does not influence on its properties, does it?

Comment: Wadim, the author of what? I am just naturally curious :-) I think that indices are shifted in different directions though. Where the OP has $n$, you have $b+1$, but where he has $n+1$, you have $b$, so either one of you made a misprint, or these two sequences are different...

Comment: thank you, Wadim.  I knew that this is derivative of cotangent, but I still don't know if it  is possible to find its roots :(....I am reading your paper...

Comment: Wadim: OK, I understand what you mean - indeed, shifting by 2 seems to do the trick. Sorry for being slow.

Comment: @Vladimir, I didn't intend to shift the index by 2; this was too many years ago. :-) I am happy that it now works. @Vilvarin: Be aware that I also need their roots in that paper but I could only localise them. But this seems to be the only thing one can do in such cases.

Comment: I can also point out Michael Hoffman's related paper in [Electronic Journal of Combinatorics 6 (1999), #R21] (http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_6/Abstracts/v6i1r21.html).

Comment: You are welcome! I am really surprised to see that the polynomials appear in a different context.

Answer (score 3):

To give a solution from scratch, start with the identity
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(x+s)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2\pi x}.$$
We want to prove that this extends to an identity
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(x+s)^n}=\frac{\pi^n P_n(\cos\pi x)}{\sin^n\pi x}$$
for each integer $n\ge2$, where the $P_n$ are polynomials satisfying some
nice recursion. If this holds for some $n$ then differentation yields
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(x+s)^{n+1}}
=\frac{\pi^{n+1}\cos\pi x\\, P_n(\cos\pi x)}{\sin^{n+1}\pi x}
+\frac{\pi^{n+1}\sin^2\pi x\\,P_n'(\cos\pi x)}{n\sin^{n+1}\pi x}$$
giving
$$P_{n+1}(t)=tP_n(t)+\frac{(1-t^2)}{n}P_n'(t).$$
So, in your notation, $P_n=Q_{n-2}$.

However
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{sinc}(\pi(x+s))^n
=\sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{sn}\sin^n\pi x}{\pi^n(x+s)^n}
=\frac{\sin^n\pi x}{\pi^n}\sum_{x=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{ns}}{(x+s)^n}$$
which is the above sum when $n$ is even but not when $n$ is odd. Unless
I have made some sign error (quite likely!) then your assertion holds for
odd $p$ but needs to be modified for even $p$. Note that
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(x+s)^n}=
2^{1-n}\sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(x/2+s)^n}
-\sum_{s=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(x+s)^n}$$
so this is feasible.

Comment: yes, this formula is indeed for odd p. For even p $Q_{0}(t)=t$ 